# ON CONFLICT with index column name is a syntax error

Tags: postgresql

[The docs for `INSERT INTO` on Postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html) describe the command like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name [ AS alias ] [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    [ OVERRIDING { SYSTEM | USER } VALUE ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
    [ ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]

where conflict_target can be one of:

    ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]
    ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

If I'm reading that right, it means that you can specify `index_column_name` without brackets like this:

```
INSERT TO
...
ON CONFLICT my_column
DO NOTHING
```

But in fact I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "my_column"
LINE 19: ON CONFLICT my_column
```

Have I read the documentation wrong?

I'm using Postgres 12.11.

Comment: You missed the fact that parentheses must be around the column name(s) `(my_column)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that part of the page to be a bit confusing, but I guess the "(" in:

```
( { index_column_name |
```

must be present. There are several examples on the page which all uses parantheses around the value:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
VALUES (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal'), (6, 'Associated Computing, Inc')
    ON CONFLICT (did) DO UPDATE SET dname = EXCLUDED.dname;
```

Comment: The syntax of the syntax diagrams is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/notation.html): *All other symbols, including parentheses, should be taken literally*

Comment: Drat, I thought that parenthesis was a group of things, but the group is `{ a | b | c }`. Thanks everyone.